# No Webcam Device for Acer Aspire E5-473

Tags: webcam, acer

Is there anyway to get my webcam running on Ubuntu 20.04, tried to uninstall cheese, reinstalling it. Tried installing guvcview, but still not working.

```
lfredo@alfredo-Aspire-E5-473G:~$ guvcview
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.6
GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/alfredo/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
GUVCVIEW (1): Guvcview error
     no video device found

(guvcview:5659): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:11:53.879: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:17: not a number

(guvcview:5659): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:11:53.880: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:31: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax

(guvcview:5659): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:11:53.880: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:17: not a number

(guvcview:5659): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:11:53.880: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:32: Using Pango syntax for the font: style property is deprecated; please use CSS syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other application may be using the webcam - that can cause this. Only one application at a time can use webcam. Check it out.

Comment: Short, tentative answers should not be comments! Answers should be in the answer section. Comments are for requesting clarification from the post author, suggesting improvements etc. I have removed the comments suggesting that this should be a comment as they were misleading.